# NoClassDefFoundError in the simplest tomcat web app ever

Tags: java, class, tomcat

I have an extremely simple web app for experimenting in java. I have the following java class defined:

[UtilDate.java http://www.philbair.org/samples/UtilDate_java.jpg](http://www.philbair.org/samples/UtilDate_java.jpg)

And a JSP file as follows:

[UtilDate.java http://www.philbair.org/samples/getdate_jsp.jpg](http://www.philbair.org/samples/getdate_jsp.jpg)

The tomcat folders/files look like this (this is not official syntax, just an abstract representation of the folder structure):

[UtilDate.java http://www.philbair.org/samples/tree.jpg](http://www.philbair.org/samples/tree.jpg)

```
mywebapp/WEB-INF/classes/com/udate/UtilDate.class
```

The jsp file is under the root 'mywebapp' folder (name is inconsequential), and all these are under the webapps folder in tomcat.

After compiling this java class (UtilDate.java), I restart tomcat to make sure it's not hanging on to any old cache stuff.

I get the following...

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: UtilDate
```

when I try to put the jsp page in the browser.

If I replace the `uDate()` method in the print statement of the jsp file with

```
out.print("hello");
```

I get the word hello on the browser output.

This is crude code for testing a simple web app. I am not looking for advice on best practices (although that advice is excellent from what I've seen on this site), I just want to know why this doesn't work. It worked once, and after recompiling the class, it stopped working. I can run the class on my command line and it works just fine (outputs the date as in the main method).

I'm running Windows 7, and tomcat 7.0.34. I'm not using eclipse, or netbeans, etc. at the moment. I'm using a simple text editor, compiling the java class with the command line `javac`, creating the web folders manually, and placing all the files where they belong myself instead of having maven or ant or anything else build it for me. No war file at the moment. Just working with the files right in the tomcat folders under webapps. I know there are more sophisticated and recommended ways of doing this, but it's only a test for my own understanding with nothing to shield me from what's going on.

Again, this worked once.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you have `package com.udate` in your `UtilDate` class? It's not present in your screenshot at least.

Comment: try: `out.print(com.udate.UtilDate.uDate());`

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add the statement `package com.udate;` at the top of your java class. Add and compile , you should be through

Comment: I did forget to add that statement. I added it, recompiled, restarted tomcat, and unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: can you try this UtilDate u = new UtilDate();

Comment: I tried that, and it worked. I don't understand why it worked before without that statement. My (possibly flawed) understanding is that if a method is declared as static, it's not necessary to create an instance variable for the object based on that class before you can use the method. I might be missing something.

Comment: @PhilBair you mean you can call `uDate()` from an instance but not statically (from the class)?